# How to declare and update Global variables in mongodb aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I want to change the **algorithm code written in JS** to **Mongodb aggregate** for better performance and scope. MongoDB provides some custom powerful features like **$function, $accumulator** which can solve my global variables issue but unfortuantly digital ocean mongodb does not allow **server scide scripting** so i have to use built in aggregate stages for this.

This is the Algorithm written in JS:-

```
 // make new algo with capabilities of carry forward reserver advance & payable ---------

  let calcAdvance = 0; //holds calculated advance
  let adReserve = 0; //holds reserve advance
  let prevPayable = 0; //holds arreras

  let algo = (bills || []).forEach((item, idx) => {
    if (item.bill === "ADVANCE_PAYMENT") {
      calcAdvance += parseFloat(item.fromAdvance); //10000
      if (prevPayable && prevPayable > adReserve + calcAdvance) {
        //1000
        prevPayable -= adReserve + calcAdvance;
        calcAdvance = 0;
        adReserve = 0;
      } else {
        calcAdvance += adReserve - prevPayable;
        prevPayable = 0;
        adReserve = 0;
      }
      //----------------------------------------
      totalAdvance += parseFloat(item.fromAdvance);
      //----------------------------------------
    }
    if (item.bill === "INVOICE" && item.type !== "OPD") {
      //-----------------------------------------
      fullGrandTotal += parseFloat(item.payable);
      //-----------------------------------------
      if (adReserve > 0) {
        adReserve += calcAdvance;
        item.currentAdvance = adReserve;
        //check for advance payment reserved or left
        if (adReserve > parseFloat(item.payable)) {
          adReserve = adReserve - parseFloat(item.payable); //change grandtotal to payNow
        } else {
          prevPayable = 0 + parseFloat(item.payable) - adReserve; //change grandtotal to payNow
          adReserve = 0;
        }
        calcAdvance = 0;
      } else {
        item.currentAdvance = calcAdvance;
        //set totalPrevPayable to next invoice
        item.prevPayable = prevPayable; // new addition set prevPayable to next invoice

        if (calcAdvance > parseFloat(item.payable) + prevPayable) {
          //new addition add prevPayable
          adReserve = calcAdvance - (parseFloat(item.payable) + prevPayable);
          prevPayable = 0;
        } else {
          prevPayable += parseFloat(item.payable) - calcAdvance;
        }
        calcAdvance = 0;
      }
    }
  });
```

And this is the aggregate Code:-

```
  const bills = await Bill.aggregate([
    {
      $addFields: {
        patient: { $toString: "$patient" },
      },
    },
    {
      $match: {
        patient: patientId,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        foreignField: "_id",
        localField: "author",
        as: "author",
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "addmissions",
        foreignField: "_id",
        localField: "addmission",
        as: "addmission",
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "invoices",
        let: { invoiceId: "$invoice" },
        pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$invoiceId"] } } }],
        as: "invoice",
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "advancepayments",
        let: { advancePaymentId: "$advancePayment" },
        pipeline: [
          { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$advancePaymentId"] } } },
        ],
        as: "advancePayment",
      },
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        author: { $arrayElemAt: ["$author", 0] },
        addmission: { $arrayElemAt: ["$addmission", 0] },
        advancePayment: { $arrayElemAt: ["$advancePayment", 0] },
        invoice: { $arrayElemAt: ["$invoice", 0] },
      },
    },

    /* -------------------------------CALCULATIONS---------------------------------- */
    /* -------------------------------CALCULATIONS---------------------------------- */
  ]);
```

So how can i use global variables like i have used in js code outside foreach methode